# How to access values stored in a global variable

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, global-variables

in the below code i assign value to a varuable declared global as follows:

```
@app.route("/getDistance/<string:startAndEndCoords>", methods=['GET'] )
def getDistance(startAndEndCoords):
    global gpsCoordinates
    gpsCoordinates = startAndEndCoords
```

i want to use that variable that is declared globally in the getter methods posted below:

```
def getStartLng():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[0]
    
def getStartLat():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[1]
    
def getEndtLng():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[2]
    
def getEndLat():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[3]
```

when i run the code, i get the following

```
4564242.9 km from Lng1:, Lat1: to Lng2:, Lat2:
```

empty values.

please let me know how to access values in a global variable
**code**:

```
def getStartLng():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[0]
    
def getStartLat():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[1]
    
def getEndtLng():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[2]
    
def getEndLat():
    return getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)[3]

def getBaseURL(gpsCoordinates):
    gpsCoordinatesAsArray = getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)
    startLng, startLat, endLng, endLat = gpsCoordinatesAsArray
    baseURL = config['EndPoint']['https'] + config['EndPoint']['url'] + config['EndPoint']['api_key'] + "&start=" + startLng + "," + startLat+ "&end=" + endLng + "," + endLat
    print("baseURL: %s"%(baseURL))
    return baseURL
@app.route("/getDistance/<string:startAndEndCoords>", methods=['GET'] )
def getDistance(startAndEndCoords):
    global gpsCoordinates
    gpsCoordinates = startAndEndCoords
    distance = 'distance could not be fetched.please enter four comma separated values and observe the order in which the coordinates must follow startLongitude,startLatitude,endLongitude,endLatitude'
    isCohesiveData = checkDataCohesion(gpsCoordinates)
    if (isCohesiveData):
        print("data is cohesive")
        data = fetchDataForURL(getBaseURL(gpsCoordinates))
        distance = fetchJSONForDistance(data)
    else:
        print("data is not cohesive")
        return distance  
    
    gpsCoordinatesAsArray = getGpsCoordinatesAsArray(gpsCoordinates)
    return distance + ' km from Lng1:%s, Lat1:%s to Lng2:%s, Lat2:%s'%(getStartLng, getStartLat, getEndtLng, getEndLat)
```

Comment: Could you also share the code of `getGpsCoordinatesAsArray()`

Comment: This line `return distance + ' km from Lng1:%s, Lat1:%s to Lng2:%s, Lat2:%s'%(getStartLng, getStartLat, getEndtLng, getEndLat)` isn't calling the functions. I think you're looking for something more like `return distance + ' km from Lng1:%s, Lat1:%s to Lng2:%s, Lat2:%s'%(getStartLng(), getStartLat(), getEndtLng(), getEndLat())`.